# Select Data by Id PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have trouble to select a set of specific data using ID from the database. For example, employee one has a unique id of e000000001, when I click the view button in the index will lead to employee detail page which shows the detail of that particular employee instead of all the employees' detail. Thank you.

//from index.php page

```
    <?php
    require_once 'db/dbEmpList.php';
    $sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM employees;";

    $result = $connection->query($sqlStr);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {



        echo "<table class='table table-sm'><thread><tr><th>Full Name</th><th>Employee ID</th><th>Position</th><th>View Employee's Details</th></tr>";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo "<tr><td>" 
            . $row["empName"]. "</td><td>" 
                    . $row["empID"]. "</td><td>" 
                    . $row["position"]. "</td>" 
                    . "<td> <a href='employeedetail.php?id={$row["empID"]}'>View</a>"
                    . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }
```

// from employee page

```
require_once 'db/dbEmpDetail.php'; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees where empID = '{$row["empID"]}' "; 
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) { 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        echo '<tr>' .'<td>' .$row["empName"].'</td>'.'<td>'. $row["position"].'</td>' .'<td>'.$row["empNRIC"].'</td>' .'<td>'.$row["empID"].'</td>' .'<td>'.$row["empEmail"].'</td>' .'<td>'.$row["empPwd"].'</td>' . "</tr>";
    } 
} else { 
    echo "0 results";
} 
mysqli_close($connection); 
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you need to write `employeedetail.php`. This isn't a question we can answer for you.

Comment: You forgot to describe anything about the problem.  "I have trouble" doesn't really tell us what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The data that I retrieved from the database is all the employee. I don't know how to retrieve a specific set of data by Id.

Comment: @wen: So you're asking how to get specific data from a database in PHP?  I'm *fairly certain* there are tutorials and examples to help with this.  The SQL keyword you're looking to use is called: `WHERE`.  For example: `SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn = ?`

Comment: @David Thanks for replying.  I  tired of using where but it is not working. The ID cannot be stated in the select statement. It depends on which view button that the user clicks on the index page which leads to a specific page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// FROM EMPLOYEE PAGE

The way you retrieve URL query string is wrong. You should be using $_GET to get the query string from URL. In your case it should be $_GET['id']. See the code below:

```
require_once 'db/dbEmpDetail.php';
$employeeid = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees where empID = '".$employeeid."' "; 
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) { 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        echo '<tr>' .'<td>' .$row["empName"].'</td>'.'<td>'. $row["position"].'</td>' .'<td>'.$row["empNRIC"].'</td>' .'<td>'.$row["empID"].'</td>' .'<td>'.$row["empEmail"].'</td>' .'<td>'.$row["empPwd"].'</td>' . "</tr>";
    } 
}
else { 
    echo "0 results";
} 
mysqli_close($connection); 
?>
```

Comment: You are accessing the $_GET without any sensitization.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Yes, I have edited my answer. $_GET should always escaped/sanitized. Thanks for reminding :D!

Comment: @muhammadUsman  Thanks for the help.  I can get the right detail. Thank you!